Symmetry of 2nd order partial difference operators
In multivariable calculus, we know that 2nd order partial derivative operators are symmetric according to the Clairaut's Theorem, which says that if a binary function $f(x, y)$ has continuous 2nd order partial derivatives in some neighbourhood of a point $(x, y)$, then the following is true:
$D_1(D_2(f(x, y))) = D_2(D_1(f(x, y)))$
where $D_i$ represents the partial derivative operator with respect to the $i$th argument.
Now in the study on finite differences, we may also define partial difference operators. For example, $\Delta_1 f(x, y) = f(x + 1, y) - f(x, y)$ and $\Delta_2 f(x, y) = f(x, y + 1) - f(x, y)$. I wonder whether there are any conditions for the symmetry of these partial difference operators, i.e. what conditions must $f$ satisfy so that the following is true:
$\Delta_1(\Delta_2(f(x, y))) = \Delta_2(\Delta_1(f(x, y)))$
Or is this true for any function?

This is true for any function. Using the definition of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$, along with simple algebra, you can show that both sides of that equation evaluate to $f(x+1,y+1)-f(x,y+1)-f(x+1,y)+f(x,y)$.
